# Mixing javascript and jquery within namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, firebug

Was having trouble a few weeks ago getting jquery to run in firebug (esp on drupal sites). Apparently the issue was that Drupal was grabbing the $ variable, so I got a little namespace snippet (function($)...(Jquery)); that reclaimed the $. I have been using the namespace in firebug but geting inconsistent results, especially when mixing pure javascript and Jquery within the namespace. I understand that all Jquery is javascript and they work together, but looking at samples I see some weird variations in the way people deploy this namespace. As a general question but also specifically within Firebug context, is there any need to place javascript in any particular relation to namespaced Jquery (inside the namespace, function calls inside, function out, or any other convention)? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant preventing the `$` from being reclaimed, there is no convention but there is a way. other frameworks also use the `$` name. anything declared later to use `$` will take over `$`. however, you can prevent it or get around it.

jQuery offers a lot of ways to prevent it via its [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method. but my preferred method is just wrap them in a function. jQuery also uses the `jQuery` namespace. `$` is a shorthand alias, a very common one too. so functions like `$.each()` is also `jQuery.each()`. what crazy framework uses jQuery as its namespace anyway?

an example of wrapping in a function is like this:

```
(function($){

    //inside here, "$" is jQuery

}(jQuery)); //pass "jQuery"
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, this is the same namespacing snippet I have, I guess I was just more interested in javascript and namespacing generally. I was trying to puzzle out the use of this snippet by looking at stack overflow examples and I have seen a lot of weird things. People strictly separating js, not allowing any within the jquery namespace, Ive also seen people who keep javascript function calls within the jquery namespace, but all actual functions defined outside of it, I just don't get why?

Comment: I guess I should add, I do sometimes have weird problems within firebug console which I magically solve by separating the jquery and the pure js, the conventional wisdom is that this shouldn't matter, but I have magically fixed code by doing it, kind of want to get to the bottom of it?